# Adding default gateway using nmcli - Centos 8

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, centos8, nmcli

I am trying to add 2 default gateways on my Centos8 server with different interface names and metrics. I have a route file for each interface with the route "default via  metric ". This is not working as I don't see the routes when I specify "ip route show all". Looks like NetworkManager is not considering the route files with default gateway. So I add the default route using "ip route add" command. This becomes a problem since this doesn't persist on reboot. Any idea how to achieve this and make it persistent?

Comment: Why not use route add ? route add default gw 192.168.0.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth1.

Comment: @Overmind ip route add works well but the routes don't persist after a reboot right?

Comment: For persistent routes, you can create them in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` for example. And the syntax is: `192.168.40.0/24 via 192.168.30.1 dev eth1`

Comment: As Ron said, they can be made persistent.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the issue. Default routes cannot be added using the route files. I can only add gateway inside the ifcfg file. Thanks anyway.